# Interesting set problem involving cardinality of sets, intersection and union.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-set-theory, arithmetic

I'm stucked on the following problem of an Algebra book in Spanish I've been working on. The problem goes as following: If #A = 4 and #B = 7 and #A ∩ B = 3, then #A ∪ B is:
(4), (7), (8), (9), (11)
The correct answer is (8), but... How can I develop the question and get to it?
I get kind of confused when cardinality of a set intersects with a set, How may I work this on?

Comment: Do you know how many elements there are in A which do not belong to B? Conversely, how many elements in B which are not in A?

Comment: [Inclusion exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) implies that $|A\cup B| = |A|+|B|-|A\cap B|$

Comment: Thanks you very much, I really appreciate your answers. Of course, you effectively get to the answer with the principle of inclusion exclusion, and hence end up with union being equal to 8.

Comment: You should be reading $\#A \cap B$ as $\#(A \cap B)$  The cardinality does not intersect, it is the cardinality of the intersection.

Comment: But, given those case, what happens with the B in the union, shall be a cardinality as well?

Comment: Or cardinality of the union of A and B...

Comment: ... in this case would be a typo in the book?, Or is there any more involved we are not taking into account?

Comment: It isn't necessarily a typo, it is just poor notation.  The `#` here is just talking about the fact that what follows (*which includes all of "A ∪ B"*) is having the cardinality taken of it.  Think of it as even lower in the order of operations than addition,subtraction,union, etc...

Comment: The most intriguing is that there is another problem like this one... If A⊂B and #B = 12 and #A = 6, then #A∩B is:

Comment: $A\subset B \iff A\cap B = A$

Comment: Yes, it must be poor notation, makes sense. Because using the inclusion exclusion knowing that the we can operate with the cardinalities, since are the quantity of elements of a set we can get to the result. Thanks

Comment: Thanks to you, JMoravitz, too. That's how we can get to the result of the other problem

Comment: Start by considering the points in $A\cap B$, clearly they will be contained in $A\cup B$. Now examine the sets $A\setminus A\cap B$ and $B\setminus A\cap B$. These points must also be contained in $A\cup B$ and be distinct from the points in $A\cap B$. Finally, verify that there are no points in $A\cup B$ not contained in one of the above sets.

Comment: Please make subject lines informative. "Interesting" is both purely subjective, and completely uninformative. It's nothing but clickbait.